# Fix length record and creating a file

Tags: c#, file, flat

I have to create a fix length record file using C#.  I read the records from database and then after some business logic I would like to write some of the fields into a text file.
I researched this and some recommend using an XML to define the file, while others format the string and then write that into a file.

Is there a proper way to do this?  I would like to keep this object oriented.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at http://www.filehelpers.com/ to export the data to a fixed file format. you may also want to look at http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-etl to create a process that runs the export for you. rhino.etl includes operations for FileHelpers.

Comment: Great resources. I was just about to post the very same links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jet to parse fixed length records in a text file. This is a decent overview that should be able to get you started:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/08/25/reading-fixed-length-files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the past when i've done this, I pull the data out of SQL as a Char(Length) so that the padding is handled by SQL.  This makes the C# pretty easy to put together.  You can do this by casting or converting the data when you select it, or by creating a table that is the exact format of your file and inserting the data in there before pulling it out into C#.